# Create JS Object in Bigcommerce

Tags: javascript, object, bigcommerce

I want to add a JavaScript object that includes order information such as order number, ordered products and total amount of order to the checkout success page. I've made some research on documentation but couldn't figure it out. Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far, and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve a JSON object containing information about the just-placed order on the confirmation page with the storefront orders API:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/storefront.html#/reference/order